# Using Terminal to rename certain numbered files

Tags: terminal, rename, range

I have a series of files numbered 1-20, and Terminal sorts them like this:

> ```
> episode1.txt
> episode10.txt
> episode11.txt
> episode12.txt
> ```

I want to rename the files 1-9 by inserting a 0 in front of the number. My code is the following:

```
for file in episode{1-9}.txt
do
   rename -vs "episode"* "episode0"*
done
```

I have also tried the 'mv' command, but it does not work. Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enumerate a sequence, use `{x..y}` instead of `{x-y}`.

Since all your files have a very similar name, we can use parameter expansion to chop off the prefix `episode` while replacing it with `episode0`.

The full command looks like this:

```
for file in episode{1..9}.txt
do
    mv "$file" "episode0${file#episode}"
done
```

`${file#episode}` is a parameter expansion that, in this case, expands the parameter `file` while removing the shortest prefix pattern that matches `episode`.